# Binding to a Property and Passing a Custom StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently building a helper class that converts decimal format coordinates into human readable ones.

I want to be able to bind to a coordinate and pass a custom format that I define. In my Coordinate class I have defined these 2 methods.

```
  public override string ToString()
  {
       return ToDegreeMinuteSecondString(1); //returns N ### ##' ###"
  }
  public string ToString(string format)
  {
     switch(format)
     {
         case "DMS": 
             return ToDecimalDegreeMinuteString(1); // returns N ### ##.###'               
     }
  }
```

I left all the other cases out to keep it simple as they aren't important.

From here I try to bind to the class property in my XAML, and pass a string format, but it won't take. I have tried different formats and I either get conversion errors or it defaults to the ToString() override method.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mw, Path=DataContext.Latitude, StringFormat='DMS'}"/>
```

I am fine implementing a converter to handle this, but I would like to know if creating and passing custom defined string formats is possible. It would make life easier. I have searched everywhere to no avail.

EDIT: I had to implement IFormattable on my Coordinate class. Works like a charm and I can avoid converters. I freaking love it!

```
class Coordinate : IFormattable
{
  //Properties Omitted
  public override string ToString()
  {
       return ToDegreeMinuteSecondString(1); //returns N ### ##' ###"
  }
  public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
    switch(format)
    {
        case "DMS": 
           return ToDecimalDegreeMinuteString(1); // returns N ### ##.###'               
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to implement `ICustomFormatter` on your class if you want it to be used by `string.Format`-- which is likely where that `StringFormat` attribute is ending up

Comment: IFormattable ended being what i needed to implement, but your answer led me in the right direction. Will edit my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a `StringFormat` to the `binding` won't automatically cause your `ToString(string format)` method to get called if that's what you think.

What you could to is to use a converter that calls the method for you:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Coordinate c = value as Coordinate;
            if(c != null)
            {
                return c.ToString(parameter as string);
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Grid xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mw, Path=DataContext.Latitude, Converter={StaticResource conv}, ConverterParameter='DMS'}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to call ToString(string format). I always use converters, but I wanted to see if there was another way. I just assumed you could create a StringFormat extension method, or custom format somehow. Thanks for the info.